# Snapping grid to a point

Tags: qgis, point, vector-grid, snapping

I am trying to snap the edge of a grid to a point (red point). I drew my grid with the correct dimensions, but how can I align the top left of my grid to my point/a set of coordinates? I am using QGis 3.22.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

`Enable Snapping` (1), use `Select features` (2) to select the features of the grid you want to move, `Toggle editing` (3), click `Move Feature(s)` (4) and shift the upper left point of the grid until it snaps to the point (5).

[image]

Comment: You're welcome. As a new user, please be adviced that this side tries to avoid "thank you" messages. Instead, it encourages you to accept the answer and/or upvote it: click the checkmark right to the answer to accept it - see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers
Just click the checkmark, see here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235